# jupyter notebook raises AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am using a jupyter notebook to test my python package but jupyter raises the following issue when I try to run my package:

```
AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'config'
```

There is a similar question here: [Jupyter Notebook - Attribute Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'F_OK'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53323898/9863397)
But the solution (downgrade conda and python) is not satisfying to me. Does anyone have another idea? For now I just comment the line in my code and it works but it is not very handy...

Comment: What is the code from `logging` and the attempted import or usage? Does it run in a CLI or other code editor but not in Jupyter?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add `import logging.config` and it should fix your issue.